# The best practice to distinguish DTO for view and for action

Tags: java, dto, spring-restcontroller, conventions

can you tell me what are the best practices to distinguish DTO's which serve for transfer data for frontend (for instance show user profile) and DTO's which serve for some action (for instance create user, update user, ...)

What do you think about naming like this:

`CreateUserDto`, `UpdateUserDto` for action and `UserDto`, `UserBaseDto` for showing data on FE? I was also thinking about using suffix `Command` like `CreateUserCommand` instead of DTO suffix.

Comment: Imho, `CreateUserCommand` feels like the class has further responsibilities than just a bare DTO.  I think `CreateUserDto`has a meaningful name to easily identify the purpose of the class.

Answer (score 0):

There's no distinction - in both cases you're talking about data *transfer* object. It's what sent back and/or forth. Moreover if your UI creates a user then it may use the same structure (hence same DTO) for GETing and POSTing - which I think is a widespread scenario.

There are no common conventions and thus your question boils down to "how to name a class or a package in my particular case" which opens a lot of possibilities. Like CreateUserDto that you suggested, or UserCreationRequestDto, or simply putting these classes into different packages.

Command is a GoF design pattern which has nothing to do with DTOs, so it may lead to confusion.